# problem 292 gelfand algebra proof problem

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that for $a>1$, the value of $a^p$ increases when $p$ increases. Prove that for $0 < a < 1$, the value of $a^p$ decreases when $p$ increases.
>
> Hint. When comparing two values of $p$, find the common denominator. Do not forget that $p$ may be negative (and the statement of the problem remains true).

How do I solve using mathematical induction or direct proof

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial.  Is $p$ an integer?

Comment: Fix a. Consider the function $x\rightarrow a^x$

Comment: thanks, let's say p is a rational number m/n

Comment: I should mention that this question is in an algebra book. there is no mention of calculus

Comment: Have you tried applying the hint?  Where do you run into difficulty?

Comment: not sure how to start the proof, my attempt is as follows:                                     since a>1 then a^(p+1)>1 so a^p . a^1>1 and also > a^p

Answer (score 0):

I assume logarithms aren't considered to be "calculus material" so I will say this. Suppose $a^{p_1} > a^{p_2}$. Now by taking the natural log of both sides (which preserves the inequality) we get $$\ln a^{p_1} > \ln a^{p_2}$$ $$= p_1 \ln a > p_2 \ln a$$

Now what happens when we divide both sides by $\ln a$ when $a > 1$? When $a$ is between $0$ and $1$?